# Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled in order for this application to display correctly

Tags: java, swing

I displayed webpage on JEditorPane, but it is getting message as "**Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled in order for this application to display correctly.**"

[image]

Below is code

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class EricPage {

    public EricPage() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
         jep.setEditable(false);   

         try {
           jep.setPage("http://corp.netsapiens.com");
         }
         catch (IOException e) {
           jep.setContentType("text/html");
           jep.setText("<html>Could not load Web Site");
         } 

         JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jep);     
         JFrame f = new JFrame("Display WebPage");
         // Next line requires Java 1.3
         f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
         f.setSize(512, 342);
         f.show();
}
}
```

Please let me know how to resolve

Comment: *"Please let me know how to resolve"*  I thought I'd covered that in your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10205917/418556)!  ***JEditorPane is not a browser, as alluded to by the author of the code you linked!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JEditorPane renders only basic HTML and CSS (HTML 3.2). It does not support JavaScript. See [HTMLEditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html) for details.